# How do fetch Google Drive API Application Specific data in browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-drive-api

I have a website app in which I want to store and fetch app specific data. The docs don't mention how to fetch in a browser, only regular downloads for desktop apps. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#viewing_files_in_a_browser https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

I want to be able to fetch this data without initiating a file download in the browser

Answer (score 0):

**To list available application data in Browser, in the same way as performed in the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata#search_for_files_in_the_application_data_folder) in other programming languages, the steps are:**

- Build a gapi client and perform a [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) request based on the [quickstart for Browser](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)
- What you need to change compared to the quickstart is:

  **Specify the `gapi.client.drive.files.list` request parameter `'spaces': 'appDataFolder'`**
- Also: provide the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`

*Sample based on the quickstart:*

```js
//  multiple scopes can be included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata';
...
// Build the gapi client
...
function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'spaces': 'appDataFolder',
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }
```